# C++ Segmentation Fault with Pointer/Non Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, allocation

It tell me there is a segmentation fault here :

```
class Atelier  /* Director qui va executer les méthodes du monteur */
{

private:
MonteurVoiture *_monteur;

public:
Voiture* doTheJob();
Atelier(MonteurVoiture *mont);

};

int main()
{

MonteurVoiture *monteur=MonteurVoiture::instanceVoiture("luxe");
Atelier a(monteur);
cout << a.doTheJob() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Without `cout << a.doTheJob() << endl;` it works . If I replace it by cout << "ok"; it's ok.
So the segmentation fault come from this method.

```
Atelier::Atelier(MonteurVoiture *mont) { _monteur=mont; }

Voiture* Atelier::doTheJob()
 {
 _monteur->createVoiture();
 _monteur->addPortiere();
 _monteur->addSiege();
 return _monteur->getVoiture();
}
```

The class Voiture

```
class Voiture
{

private:
std::string portiere;
std::string siege;

public:
void setPortiere(std::string p);
void setSiege(std::string s);
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o,const Voiture *v);
};
```

and the class MonteurVoiture

```
class MonteurVoiture  
{

protected:
Voiture *v;

public:
~MonteurVoiture();
Voiture* createVoiture();
Voiture* getVoiture();
virtual void addPortiere() =0;
virtual void addSiege() =0;
static MonteurVoiture* instanceVoiture(std::string type);
};

Voiture* MonteurVoiture::createVoiture() { return new Voiture(); }

Voiture* MonteurVoiture::getVoiture() { return v; }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the question is what's Voiture class look like? Especially `Voiture::getVoiture()`

Comment: Okay now what's the imlementation of `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o,const Voiture *v);` ? :-)

Comment: This is it :
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o,const Voiture *v)
{
    return o << "Porte en " << v->portiere << " et siege en " << v->siege;
}

Comment: that's where your segfault is. let me suggest an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Fix

Okay first to fix your problem:

```
class MonteurVoiture  
{

protected:
       Voiture *v; // how is this being set??? 

public:
            ~MonteurVoiture();
    Voiture* createVoiture();
    Voiture* getVoiture();
    virtual void addPortiere() =0;
    virtual void addSiege() =0;
    static MonteurVoiture* instanceVoiture(std::string type);
};

Voiture* MonteurVoiture::createVoiture() { return MonteurVoiture::v = new Voiture(); }
                                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  you need this
Voiture* MonteurVoiture::getVoiture() { return v; }
```

The problem occurs because you are not setting Voiture *v value at all but you are using it in doTheJob():

```
Voiture* Atelier::doTheJob()
 {
     _monteur->createVoiture();
     _monteur->addPortiere();
     _monteur->addSiege();
     return _monteur->getVoiture(); /* this is undefined without the fix in createVoiture() above */
}
```

## Overall Design Issues

Your object design is very weird. You have a Car (Voiture class) and then you are applying modifications to it in MonteurVoiture is what's controlling the car?

You may consider a construction like the following:

```
class Option {
public:
      virtual std::string name() = 0; /* name of the option */
      void add(Voiture &v) {
             v.addOption(this);
      }   
      virtual std::string getDetails() = 0;  /* details of the option */
};

class optionDeSeiges: public Option {
public:
      virtual inline std::string name() { return "Sieges"; }
};

virtual std::string getDetails() {

}

class Voiture {
      std::List<Option *> options; /* an array of options */
      void addOption(Option *o) {
           options.add(o);
      }
}
```

### NOTE: above is pseudo code for the most part, it's supposed to show you alternate concepts, take ideas from it don't copy it verbatim.

Comment: First , thanks you , it works .
Then , it not works exactly . I replaced { return Voiture::v = new Voiture(); } by { return MonteurVoiture::v = new Voiture(); } and here , it works.
Third : It's not a real object design , I'm just a debutant developer which is programming about few month and I decided to see the design patterns ( here the Builder ).
Otherwise , thanks you so much :-)

Comment: Woops I meant to write MonteurVoiture::v :P

Answer (score 0):

I used Valgrind and it says :

```
==19269==    at 0x38B0D: std::string::assign(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==19269==    by 0x100001E02: Voiture::setPortiere(std::string) (in ./main.exe)
==19269==    by 0x1000018AA: MonteurVoitureLuxe::addPortiere() (in ./main.exe)
==19269==    by 0x10000120C: Atelier::doTheJob() (in ./main.exe)
==19269==    by 0x100002029: main (in ./main.exe)
```

The addPortiere method from MonteurVoitureLuxe

```
void MonteurVoitureLuxe::addPortiere() { v->setPortiere("diamand"); }
```

And the setPortiere from Voiture

```
void Voiture::setPortiere(std::string p) { this->portiere=p; }
```